# Accessing parent model instance within model admin to provide custom queryset

Tags: django, model, django-admin

I want to provide a custom queryset within a model admin class that inherits from TabluarInline, but I want to provide this queryset by calling a method of current instance of the model object.

I have two models. One for tracks belonging to an album, and one for the Album itself. Some tracks can be hidden and I have a method in Album to return only the visible tracks.

```
class Track(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    length = models.IntegerField()
    album = ForeignKey(Album)
    hidden = BooleanField()

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def get_visible_tracks_queryset(self):    
        return self.track_set.filter(hidden=False)
```

And I have a tracks inline admin which is included on the django admin page for an album. I want to re-use the get_visible_tracks_queryset to define the queryset for this inline admin, I don't want to repeat the logic again. I can't figure out how to do it. I could do something like the following, however I'm using a simplified example here, I actually have more complex logic and I don't want to be repeating the logic in multiple places.

```
class TracksInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    fields = ("name", "length")
    model = Track

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(TracksInlineAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.filter(hidden=False)
```

Ideally I could do something like:

```
class TracksInlineAdmin(admin.TabularInline):
    fields = ("name", "length")
    model = Track

    def get_queryset(self, request, parent_model_instance):
        return parent_model_instance.get_visible_tracks_queryset()
```

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: This `.filter(hidden=False)` (or something more complex) is typically a method you should implement as a custom `QuerySet` `def visible()` on your model's manager, not on your model instances. That way, in `get_queryset` you'll do your first method but using `return qs.visible()`. You don't need to actual model instance since the queryset returned by `super().get_queryset()` is already only containing the related instances.

Comment: Thanks dirkgroten ... this looks a nice solution. However one more question ...

The way you propose it looks like the logic inside my Manager method is applied first then the filter on foreign key is applied by the inline admin. Unfortunately this makes it quite slow, because I'm doing multiple calculations to decide the queryset, and this is happening over millions of un-filtered records, the process is quite slow. 

I would prefer to filter on the foreign key first, reducing my dataset to about 10 or so records, then run my logic on this reduced queryset. 

Is this possible?

Comment: No, `qs = super().get_queryset(request)` should apply the fk filter, then you add `return qs.visible()` which applies the visible filter *after* the fk filter. Not sure how you get the reverse.

Comment: Did you change the default queryset? That was not what I intended...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was calling super().get_queryset inside my "visible()" function. 

All working now. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is to define a custom `QuerySet` class for your model in which you can define any complex filters for re-use in various places:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    # fields defined here

    objects = TrackManager()


class TrackManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return TrackQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db)


class TrackQuerySet(models.QuerySet):

    def visible(self):
        return self.filter(hidden=False)
```

Now, anywhere in code, when you have a queryset of tracks (e.g. `Track.objects.filter(name="my movie")`) you can add `.visible()` to filter further. Also on a related set:

```
album.track_set.all().visible()
```

Comment: Does this really solve the question? I am looking for a way to get the parent object in `InlineModelAdmin.get_queryset()`

Comment: In the case of the question, `qs = super(TracksInlineAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)` so adding `return qs.visible()` does the job. You don't need the parent object, by calling `super` you already get the correct subset of children.

Comment: It depends on the use-case sometimes the filtering needs an attribute of the parent-object. In above question the author does not show `parent_model_instance.get_visible_tracks_queryset()`, so we don't know.